# In next js _document.js giving this error

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

Below is image of error I don't know how should I fix that I am new to next js and I am trying to add material-ui with next js.

I also added _document.js whole code that followed by one tutorial I am trying to fix that from last few hours but it's not fixing i don't know what i missed.

Any help would bi appreciated, Thanks in advance.

[image]

This is my _document.js code.

```js
import React from 'react';
import Document, {
  Html,
  Main,
  NextScript,
  Head,
} from 'next/document';
import {
  ServerStyleSheets
} from '@material-ui/core/styles';

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return ( <
      Html lang = "en" >
      <
      Head / >
      <
      body >
      <
      Main / >
      <
      NextScript / >
      <
      /body> <
      /Html>
    );
  }
}

// `getInitialProps` belongs to `_document` (instead of `_app`),
// it's compatible with server-side generation (SSG).
MyDocument.getInitialProps = async(ctx) => {

    // Render app and page and get the context of the page with collected side effects.
    const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets();
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

    ctx.renderPage = () => originalRenderPage({
        enhanceApp: (App) => (props) => sheets.collect( < App { ...props
          }
          />),
        });

      const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);

      return {
        ...initialProps,
        // Styles fragment is rendered after the app and page rendering finish.
        styles: [...React.Children.toArray(initialProps.styles), sheets.getStyleElement()],
      };
    };
```

Comment: Are you setting the `style` prop to a string anywhere in your code by any chance?

Comment: No @juliomalves

Answer (score 0):

I don't know ,if you are using Material UI version 5 with nextjs. This is for mui v5

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import { ServerStyleSheets } from '@mui/styles';

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheets();
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

    try {
      ctx.renderPage = () =>
        originalRenderPage({
          enhanceApp: (App) => (props) => sheet.collect(<App {...props} />),
        });

      const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
      return {
        ...initialProps,
        styles: (
          <>
            {initialProps.styles}
            {sheet.getStyleElement()}
          </>
        ),
      };
    } finally {
      ctx.renderPage(sheet);
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
         
         
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon(1).ico" />
          <link
            rel='stylesheet'
            href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico|Raleway:100,400,400i,700|Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap'
          />
          <style>{`body { margin: 0 } /* custom! */`}</style>
      
        </Head>
        <body className='custom_class'>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument
```

;